# How prevent initialize trigger for element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My simple code:

```
<a href="#" class="init">init</a>
<a class="pure" href="#" onclick="alert('1')">trigger</a>
<a class="pure disable" href="#" onclick="alert('1')">trigger</a>

    $(".init").click(function(){        
        $(".pure").trigger('click');
    })
    $(".disable").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

I want to disable trigger on element with `$(".disable")`?

How can I do it?

UPD:

**trigger initialize by plugin and i can not correct this .**

Comment: @Micheal - Reply me you got the answer or not still

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not()` in jquery. this `:not()` method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against each element; the elements that don't match the selector will be included in the result.

```
$(".pure.disable").removeAttr('onclick');
$(".init").click(function(){
   $(".pure:not(.disable)").trigger('click');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5v89zzz8/)

[**Fiddle2**](https://jsfiddle.net/5v89zzz8/1/)

Comment: @Micheal - Reply me you got the answer or not still